# Android-Java SDK Method invocation vs NDK function invocation

Tags: java, android, performance, android-ndk

## The Question

Is it better to use the NDK for game dev when the game will be using high amounts of function calls? In the range of 1000-10000 at least probably...

## Situation

I am writing a game that I intended to run on android with advanced structure using Component Based design getting away from the [God Object anti-patern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) how ever I may have hit a wall with the game code because I have been reading and hearing about how you should never let an obj get deleted which was fine but that made more function calls which I hear will also take a huge chunk out of your performance. See: [Google I/O 2009 - Writing Real-Time Games for Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic)

## The Test

```
protected static void voidFun(Integer i){
    if(i == 4) Log.d(TAG, "This should be impossible.");
}

public static void test(){
    stressTestMillis(1000);
    stressTestMillis(10000);
    stressTestMillis(100000);
}

protected static void stressTestMillis(int loops) {
    long beforeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long before = beforeBefore;
    for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++){
        //Just measuring raw loop time not function call time.
    }
    long rawLoop = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
    Integer test = 0;
    before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++){
        voidFun(test);
    }
    long loop = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
    long total = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeBefore;
    Log.d("Stress Test", "Loops:"+loops+" Loop:"+loop+" Loop Tare:"+rawLoop+" function Total:"+(loop-rawLoop)+" Total:"+total);
}
```

#### The Results

The results of running Test()

```
12-12 18:30:22.623: D/Stress Test(15863): Loops:1000 Loop:14 Loop Tare:1 function Total:13 Total:15
12-12 18:30:22.703: D/Stress Test(15863): Loops:10000 Loop:80 Loop Tare:4 function Total:76 Total:84
12-12 18:30:23.513: D/Stress Test(15863): Loops:100000 Loop:783 Loop Tare:26 function Total:757 Total:809
```

#### The Concern

This worries me greatly because the component based design + AI (Behavior Tree) alone are a ton of function calls then throw in Physics and your looking at a lot of method calls and a lot of time 10000 is already out of range...

By my calculations `1000ms/30fps=33.333ms` per frame with `10000` function calls clocking in at `76ms` then I have already gon over budget and dropped to `1000ms/76ms=13fps`

## Bonus Points

For bonus points have I over looked something that will allow me to continue along this design path while still using java?

Comment: Which kind of devices are you targeting? Which hw/android version did you test this on?  Did you warm the cpu to get it to high freq? Did you write it in a way so it is easy to get best of dalvik(http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html) bonus: 1) make "voidFun(int ...) not Integer" 2) in android perf doc there is a part for microbenchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

1. I honestly doubt that a simple loop or a simple snippet can guide you and help you at deciding what technology is the best
2. According to the Android runtime design/architecture, programming in Java or with the NDK it's really the same thing, meaning that for both the `JVM` and the `main()` function there is 1 thread for each one allocated by default and both are "sandboxed" with no direct access to resources; so if you intend to use the NDK and you think that with C/C++ you will get a low access to the hardware like it happens on other hardware/robotic solutions you are wrong. You even get basically the same life-cycle for your application and with the C/C++ you have much less APIs to play with.
3. the decision is about re-usable code and porting existing code to Android, the speed gain shouldn't be the first thing in your list and it's most likely done through a good use of the language, since with languages like C/C++ you don't get a garbage collector or any form of automatic memory management, you can set-up and direct with more precision your resources, off-course the fact that you can do something doesn't mean that your program will magically overperform an equivalent Java based app.
4. In the industry C++ is the king, so the NDK can be your entry point to the Android world if you want to share your codebase among iOS, Blackberry, Windows 8 and so on, this is a really god reason why you should program with the NDK, not performances but the re-use of existing components.
5. many just forgot that the JNIs simply work in both ways, you can call Java methods from C++ and viceversa, also if you program with the NDK and you create a C++ only app, also know as native-activity, the JVM thread will be always allocated and you always end up having 2 threads for your apk by default.
6. there are things that are a lot easier to do in Java than with C/C++, for example just try to create a virtual interface of buttons and touch events in Java and after that try to do the same with the NDK only.
7. Android is clearly oriented to an heavy use of the Java language for an easier sandbox creation, and I think that in the end this is a necessary evil and you will probably end up using the JNI and both the Java thread and the C/C++ thread.